# Combine multiple lines (line break) into one line in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So I was crawling articles from a site but the summary had multiple paragraphs and I want them in one line.
eg.

```
Line 1 : Title 1
Line 2 : Summary para1 Summary para2
```

These are my current code from this site
https://theaizawlpost.org/health-minister-in-fimkhur-turin-mipui-ngen-nawn/

```
import csv

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import date
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen



csv_file = open('cms_scrape.csv', 'w')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['title', 'summary'])

source = requests.get('https://theaizawlpost.org/health-minister-in-fimkhur-turin-mipui-ngen-nawn/').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
article = soup.find('article')
title = article.find('span', class_='current').text
print(title)
summary = article.find('div', class_='entry-content entry clearfix').text
print(summary)


csv_writer.writerow([title, summary.strip()])
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: Could you please provide the current output and  maybe your whole code?

Comment: I edit the code with full code. When I export to csv, the summery is outputted in multiple lines. I want a single line. Open csv in ide like atom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `strip=True` argument in [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) to remove a newline (`\n`):

```
summary = article.find('div', class_='entry-content entry clearfix').get_text(strip=True)
```

Since you have already stripped the whitespace from `summary`, don't call `.strip()` when writing to the CSV file, instead, use:

```
csv_writer.writerow([title, summary])
```

Output:

```
Health minister-in fimkhur turin mipui ngen nawn
Sawrkarin May ni 31 thleng total lockdown a pawhsei leh hnuah, health minister Dr. R. Lalthangliana chuan nimin khan mipui hnena ngenna leh thuchah tichhuakin, total lockdown chu kan damkhawchhuahna tur a nih tih hriaa inkhuahkhirhna dan te tha taka zawm chunga fimkhurna ngai pawimawh zel turin mipui a chah.Health minister Dr. Thangtea chuan, kan zavaia kan tanrual a, kan tawrh leh rih hram hram a tul dawn a, chutih rualin, tumah riltam leh chhuanchhama kan awm hi sawrkarin a phal lova, kohhran leh khawtlang hruaitute, Local task Force te nen tangrualin theihtawp kan chhuah zel dawn a ni, a ti a. Hetih rual hian sum lakluhna te a lo kiam tak avangin chhungtinin mahni zawnah theuh inrenchem tum ila, fimkhur takin, chi-ai si lovin awm ila, inlenpawh lo turin leh a tul tawpkhawkah lo chuan pawn chhuak rih lo turin kan inchah nawn leh a, kan duh reng vang pawh ni lovin, nunna chhan nan kan tawrh tlan rih hram hram a ngai a ni, a ti bawk.Total lockdown kar hnih kalpui hnu pawha hri kaiin kian lam a la pan theih loh chungchangah health minister chuan, inkharkhip laiin mipui lam hi kan fimkhur tawk lo deuh em tih zawhna a awm hial a ni, a ti a. “Nikum lama khauh taka bazar-na hmuna social distancing kan zawm ang khan kan zawm ta lo em ni aw? ka ti a, mipuite pawh bazar-ah leh puipunna hmunah duty te hmuh phak loha kan awm hian kan fimkhur tawk lo palh ang tih ka hlau a. Mahni theuh kan pawimawh ber a ni tih hriain kan inkhuahkhirhna dan hi khauh deuh mah se, kan zavaia kan himna tura ruahman a ni tih i hre nawn fo ang u,” tiin mipui a chah a.Hri vanga thi awm thin chu lungchhiatthlak a tih thu sawiin health minister chuan, “Kan state-a thi zat hi a tam tawh viaua a lan laiin hmarchhak state dang te leh India ram ngaihtuah chuan kan dinhmun a la ziaawm hle a. Kan positivity rate a sang kan tih pawh hi test kan neih that vang a ni ve pakhat a, kan test percentage hi 31.49 niin hmarchhak state-ah Arunachal Pradesh tih lohah chuan test tam ber kan ni,” a ti.Vaccine chungchangah, sawrkarin vaccine a chah mek thu leh, Central Ministry lamin inkaihhruaina a siam ang zelin chak taka vaccine pek hna kalpui zel tum a nih thu a sawi a. Mizoramin khawvel ram hrang hrang United Kingdom, Egypt, Ireland, Switzerland, Turkey, China, Taiwan atangtein kan mamawh hmanrua leh khawl chi hrang hrang kan dawng tawh tih sawiin, USA, Spain leh Kuwait atang pawhin tanpuina dawn tur a la awm thu te, World Health Organisation atanga oxygen concentrator 150 dawn a nih thu te pawh a sawi bawk.Minister chuan, ram hruaitu Minister-te leh MLA zawng zawngte an thawkrim hle tih sawiin, “Kan thawhhona a thatna leh mipuite thlawpna avangin he hripui hi kan hneh ngei dawn a ni,” a ti.“Total lockdown puang tura kohhran, Local Council Association, NGO leh VC Association te bakah mi thahnemngaite ngenna a lawmawmin a zahawm ka ti hle a, nitina eizawngte lakah inthlahrunawm viau mahse state dangte pawhin lockdown lo chu kawng dang zawh tur an hre bik meuh lo tih i hre tlang ila. Lockdown chhung hian kan frontline worker te leh healthcare worker ten nasa takin hma an la a, theihtawp an chhuah a ni tih i hriatsak ang u. Kan rorelah sawisel tur leh khamkhawp loh tam tak in hmu thin tih pawh ka hria a, khawvel pum luhchhuahtu hri a ni a, mi zawng zawng min nghawng vek a, rorel thiam a har a, vawiina tha kan tih kha naktuk lawkah a lo tha leh lova, engmah experiment han tih hman a ni si lo, kan rorelah leh kan tawngkam chhuakah te in rilru kan tih nat a awm chuan khawngaihtakin min ngaidam ula, inhriatthiamna nen dawhthei takin indawm tlang ila, thurawn tha leh fing engtiklai pawhin kan dawng thei reng a ni,” health minister chuan a ti a. Pathian venhimna leh a chhanchhuahna bang lova dil turin leh, malsawm tlak ni tura mahni lamin kan tih ve theihte ti ve turin Zoram mipuite a ngen a ni.
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is replace all the newlines in the string. You can do this by

```
summary.replace("\n"," ")
```

The first string in this is what we want to replace
The second string is the what we want in that place